# Read data file in C++

Tags: c++

I have file as following:

TEST.txt

```
*Node
1,2.0,3.2
2,4.1,5.2
3,5.2,6.7
4,2.0,3.2
5,4.1,5.2
6,5.2,6.7
*Element
1,1,2,3
2,3,4,6
3,5,6,4
```

How can I read the file? To get the matrix which have element from the file:

```
Node[6,3]=[...]
Element[3,4]=[...]
```

Comment: Is this homework and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Include "fstream", declare an ifstream variable. Use var.open(fileNmae) and read just like cin: I.E. var >> stringVar.

Comment: I built code:/// ifstream meshFile("TEST.txt","r") while(getline(meshFile, line)){...} ///,but not know method to chosse data block of Node and data block of Element. Please give me some advise.

Comment: Do some if comparisons... `if(line == "*NODE")` start inputing to one place, `if(line == "*ELEMENT")` switch to the other....

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("text.txt");
    std::string line;

    std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double>> node;
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>> element;

    bool isnode = false;
    bool iselement = false;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
         if (line == "*Node")
         {
            isnode = true;
            continue;
         } else if (isnode)
         {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            double d1, d2, d3;
            char c1, c2;

            if((iss >> d1 >> c1 >> d2 >> c2 >> d3))
            {
               node.emplace_back(d1, d2, d3);
            }
         }

         if (line == "*Element")
         {
            iselement = true;
            isnode = false;
            continue;
         } else if (iselement)
         {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            int i1, i2, i3, i4;
            char c1, c2, c3;

            if((iss >> i1 >> c1 >> i2 >> c2 >> i3 >> c3 >> i4))
            {
                element.emplace_back(i1, i2, i3, i4);
            }
         }
    }

std::cout << "Printing node: " << '\n';
for (auto i = node.cbegin(); i != node.cend(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*i) << ", "
            << std::get<1>(*i) << ", "
            << std::get<2>(*i) << '\n';
}

std::cout << "Printing element: " << '\n';
for (auto i = element.cbegin(); i != element.cend(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*i) << ", "
            << std::get<1>(*i) << ", "
            << std::get<2>(*i) << ", "
            << std::get<3>(*i) << '\n';
}
std::cout << std::endl;

}
```